# R package "robCompositions" install issue

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying to install the R package robCompositions but keep getting error messages. I have tried the following so far.

1. standard install

`install.packages("robCompositions")`

2. github install as suggested by the package maintainer (https://github.com/matthias-da/robCompositions)

`library(devtools)`

`install_github("matthias-da/robCompositions", dependencies = TRUE)`

3. download package and install from the package archive file (.zip, .tar, .gz)
4. unzip the downloaded package and run standard install

`install.packages("C:/Users/SUHAS/Desktop/robCompositions_2.3.0", type="source", repos = NULL)`

5. install r tools and then install package using standard install (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/)

`install.rtools()`

`writeLines('PATH="${RTOOLS40_HOME}\\usr\\bin;${PATH}"', con = "~/.Renviron")`

`Sys.which("make")`
`## "C:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"`

`install.packages("robCompositions", type = "source")`

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be much appreciated.

I am running R version R-4.0.4

Comment: Can you tell us what happened in each of those attemps to install the package? It's not very clear what errors or issues you are facing.

Comment: Looking at all the imports and depends [robCompositions](https://github.com/matthias-da/robCompositions/blob/master/DESCRIPTION), do you have them all. A quick check is `library(help='a_pkg_needed')`, if you don't have them, install them first using `install.packages('a_pkg_needed', dependencies = TRUE)`, then install `robCompositions`. HTH

Answer (score 0):

First, apologies this is an answer and not a comment - I think it should be a comment but I don't yet have enough reputation points to comment.

I had a very similar problem. When researching it, I came across this page: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robCompositions/index.html. It looks like `robCompositions` has been removed from `CRAN`, and the reason for that is a dependency, `sROC`, has been archived? I haven't yet come up with a workaround (I guess I'm hoping it will come back onto `CRAN` at some point soon!)